# How to setup Environment Path for Python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying but do not work. I find the path where python is installed but i am blind in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're trying and what you're expecting to happen when successful. `python` is usually already installed on Ubuntu's PATH, so if you want to run Python-3.x, you'd typically use `python3` command

Comment: ("_I am trying_"): What exactly did you try? ("_I find the path_"): What path? On Ubuntu you don't normally have to setup "environment" paths like in Windows. Python 2 is installed by default, and if you install Python 3 via `apt`, it will automatically setup the paths for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/dev/python-files
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24071400).